# Java FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I am writing some Java code that allows the user to see a frame with `JLabel`, `JTextField` and `JButton`.

I want the `JLabel` to be called "Count" and I have a problem with `FlowLayout`.
I want the interface to look like this:

[image]

Instead, I have this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
package modul1_Interfate_Grafice;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Exercitiu04 implements ActionListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JLabel labelCount;
private JTextField tfCount;
private JButton buttonCount;
private int count = 0;

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Java Counter");
        labelCount = new JLabel("Counter");
        labelCount.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, labelCount);

        tfCount = new JTextField(count + " ", 10);
        tfCount.setEditable(false);
        labelCount.add(tfCount);

        buttonCount = new JButton("Count");
        labelCount.add(buttonCount);
        buttonCount.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 150);
        frame.setLocation(400, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        count++;
        tfCount.setText(count + "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercitiu04 a  = new Exercitiu04();
        a.go();
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setSize(350, 150);` should instead be `frame.pack();` ..

Comment: `frame.setLocation(400, 200)` should be `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true)` as stated by [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis). It should also be before `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: You should always put swing methods in the Event Dispatch Thread. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing - The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solve it.

Instead of `labelCount.setLayout(new FlowLayout())`;` i should have had

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: Changing this line alone doesn't solve the problem above for me. Are you sure you didn't change anything else?

Comment: Yes, this was the only change.

Comment: That's weird. When I run the program all I see is the JLabel on the JFrame.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not commented this code  `frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, labelCount);` and added  the following `frame.add(labelCount);` ?

Answer (score 0):

From description of `JLabel` class,

`JLabel` is:

> A display area for a short text string or an image, or both.

But here: `labelCount.add(tfCount)` and here `labelCount.add(buttonCount)` you're trying to put a textfield and a button into a label. In this case, positions of button and textfield are controlled by FlowLayout but position of the text in the label is not.

Instead of this, you should put all of your elements in common `JPanel`, like this:

```
    ...
    frame = new JFrame("Java Counter");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(); // JPanel has FlowLayout by default

    labelCount = new JLabel("Counter");
    labelCount.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    wrapper.add(labelCount);

    tfCount = new JTextField(count + " ", 10);
    tfCount.setEditable(false);
    wrapper.add(tfCount);

    buttonCount = new JButton("Count");
    buttonCount.addActionListener(this);
    wrapper.add(buttonCount);

    frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, wrapper);
    ...
```

And, like [MasterBlaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685662/java-flowlayout#comment64752068_38685662) said, you should put swing methods in EDT.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two things you should know about `FlowLayout`:

a) It is a default layout manager of the `JPanel` component
b) It is good for nothing.

This trivial layout cannot be achieved with `FlowLayout`. 
When doing layouts in Swing, you should familiarize yourself
with some powerful layout managers. I recommend `MigLayout` and 
`GroupLayout`.

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/*
Simple UI with a MigLayout manager.
Author Jan Bodnar
Website zetcode.com
*/

public class MigLayoutCounterEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutCounterEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Counter");
        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Count");

        createLayout(lbl, field, btn);

        setTitle("Java Counter");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        add(arg[0]);
        add(arg[1]);
        add(arg[2]);

        pack();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutCounterEx ex = new MigLayoutCounterEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });        
    }
}
```

The example is trivial. You just put the three components into the
cells.

Screenshot:

[image]